# Qgis Spatial Join: numeric values change to negative values

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I run the function "Join attributes by location" in Qgis 2.2 between a point vector layer and a polygon vector layer. When I open the resulting table of contents of point layer there is a column of numbers (fields from 10 to 13) that fail, because there is the same value in every row.

In "input" a list of unique numeric values (example: 100000000001, 100000000002, 100000000003...), in output results the same value in every row (example: -12345678, -12345678, -12345678...).

Comment: Seems like an integer overflow problem. Is it acceptable to convert the numeric values to string?

Comment: Ok it works. By setting the field: either as "real" (length - 16; precision - 2) or as "text". Many thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You're running into an integer overflow problem.

You can change the field to real or text to fix that.