# Why do field values change when exporting from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, export

Today I came across a very strange behavior of QGIS. Maybe someone knows what's going on?

I have a table with two fields which are defined as Double, with a Length of 20 and a Precision of 0. Some sample values:

```
8159080177
8159080742
8159080008
...
```

The format by the way is shape. Exporting a selection of the features results in a table that has same definitions as stated above but all values for the two columns are

```
-2147483648  
-2147483648  
-2147483648  
...
```

I get the same values when I read the features with python using `ogr`'s `<feature>.GetFieldAsInteger('<fieldname>')`. Reading it as a string returns the correct value.

What is happening here?

Comment: integer overflow

Comment: same as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90218/qgis-spatial-join-problem-with-a-column?noredirect=1#comment126470_90218

Comment: Ok, but does QGIS convert the values when writing it to a new shapefile!?

Comment: Could you describe exactly which steps you take to "Exporting a selection of the features results in a table that has same definitions "

Comment: Sure. Select a couple of features manually using 'select by rectangle' tool, save selection as dialog, save as shapefile.

Comment: It's early, and I might be wrong, but is it common to use a precision of 0 when describing a double?  Isn't that something more suited for numeric?

Comment: Integer is not a good idea if your values exceed 2^31.

Comment: The data model is not designed by me but comes from an external source.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_shapefile.html, GDAL and QGIS only create field types Integer, Real, String and Date.

So if your data was defined as `Double` by some other software, QGIS has to do some converting.

Integer is obiously wrong, so manual conversion with the field calculator to string would be the best option.